# Randomising database for insert

Tags: php, mysql, registration, sharding

Evening all, I've recently been reading the following blog post about sharding at Pinterest and I think there's some great stuff in there https://engineering.pinterest.com/blog/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet

What I'm unsure on though, is how best to decide where a brand new user should be inserted.

So for those that don't know or have bothered to read the above article, Pinterest have a number of shards, each with a number of databases on. They generate IDs for objects based on a 64 bit shifting that determines a shard, the type of object (user,pin etc..) to determine a table and the local auto-increment id for the object in question. Now they try to put pins etc. on the same database as the 'board' they are on. But for a brand new object, what would be the best way of determining the 'shard' it lives on?

For users that sign in via Facebook they use a modulus e.g

```
shard = md5(“1.2.3.4") % 4096 //4096 is the number of shards
```

But if I had a simple email/password registration form, do you think using a similar approach on email address would work for working out an initial shard? I'd assume it would have to be email in this case, otherwise they would have no way of knowing what database to validate the logging credentials against. Also I know that post is from 2015 so not too old and computing power moves quickly, but would there be a better option then using md5 here? I know the chance of a collision is minor - especially as we're just talking about hashing the email address here, but would it be worth using a different algorithm? I'm basically interested in the best way to determine a shard here and to work out how to get back to it (hence why I think it has to be email address)

Hope this all makes sense!

(p.s didn't take this with the Pinterest tag as it looks like that's just for api dev, but if someone thinks it might get better 'eyes' on the question then feel free to add it)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen thanks, pretty much clears it up for me, don't know why I didn't think of that myself (one of those moments!) If you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Is this an intellectual question?  Or are you building a system that needs to scale beyond one server?

Comment: 2015 -- CPUs have not improved much since the turn of the century.  Database tools have not changed much.  About the only significant change in the last few years has been the widespread adoption of SSDs.

Comment: 100 million email addressed can be stored in a single server -- probably no sharding needed.  (Any chance you are confusing 'shard' and 'partition'?)

Comment: No it was shards. This was more an intellectual question, I know you can store a lot on a single server but it's an interesting article and I was trying to understand some of the finer detail more in depth. Just in this instance I was thinking the email would be lost as the key if there was a collision for some reason, which is clearly wrong as it just means they would sit on the same server and it's the email that's unique. Of course there would be the same shard id when using % that's what you'd want as pointed out in the answer

Comment: If it takes 12 bits (4096=2*12) of the MD5, lots of emails will map to the same shard.  Once there, the original email string will be used, via an index, to lookup the correct row.  No collision happens (other than going to the same shard).

Comment: @RickJames I know, that's already been answered a few days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MD5 to determine the shard, there is no risk on collisions: If collisions occur then it just ends up in the same shard. The MD5 is not the key in that shard (so that is where the collision risk is removed).

The main issue in this shard method is that the number of shards is fixed, so performance in the end might be an issue (re-distributing a running environment is not easy, so in this design you are still dependent on faster machines if there is more growth then expected).

Comment: It's also worth noting that the likelihood of encountering a collision when MD5-ing string data is so low as to be virtually nonexistent, even by general hash-collision standards.